# Pyinstaller: No such file or directory: '.xlsx'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am packaging my code using pyinstaller using the below statement in powershell it completes successfully but when attempting to launch the packaged executable file I get error message.

Error Message:

> "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'BaseMap.xlsx'"

I am am new to Python and I have read forum after forum and cannot seem to figure why my xlsx file does not seem to be packaged with pyinstaller so that it can be read with the code I wrote. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

pyinstaller statement being used:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data BaseMap.xlsx;BaseMap.xlsx gmplotguiwithQT2Radius.py
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# import packages
import sys
import pandas as pd
import gmplot as gm
import PyQt5
import GmapGUI
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from GmapGUI import *

class MyForm(QDialog):
    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.search.clicked.connect(self.dispmessage)
        self.show()

    def dispmessage(self):

        # call the program from cmd line
        print ("enter file:", sys.argv[0])

        # reading data from file
        data = pd.read_excel("BaseMap.xlsx")

        # create 2 lists latitudes and longitudes
        lats = data["fldLat"]
        long = data["fldLong"]
        #bid = data['fldTgbid']
        address = data['fldAddress']
        city = data['fldCity']
        state = data['fldState']
        zipcode = data['fldZip']


        # initializing the first location coordinates
        gmp = gm.GoogleMapPlotter(lats[0], long[0], 10, apikey = 'API KEY')


        #Circle
        # Radius unit measure is Meters: 1609.34 Meters = 1 Mile | 8046.72 Meter = 5 Miles | 16093.4 Meters = 10 Miles
        for lat, lng in zip(lats, long):
            gmp.circle(lat, lng, 5632.7, 'cornflowerblue')
        #gmp.circle(lats[0], long[0], 8046.72, 'cornflowerblue')+

        #Marker
        for lati, lngi, addresses, cities, states, zipc in zip(lats, long, address, city, state, zipcode):
            gmp.marker(lati, lngi, '#DB7093', c = None, title = addresses + ' ' + cities + ' ' + states + ' ' + str(zipc))


        #Draw
        # output the locations
        gmp.draw("basemap.html")
        file = 'C:/Google Map/GoogleMap_env/basemap.html'
        self.ui.webEngineView.setUrl(QUrl(file))


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyForm()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Which of your `imports` belong to `gmplotguiwithQT2Radius.py`.

Comment: Sorry, Not sure if I am understanding the question being asked. I am using all import on gmplotguiwithQT2Radius.py, but I will say that (import GmapGUI) is the only one that does not belong but is being used so that the map shows on a GUI that I created over a web browser. Not sure if this is what you r were looking for?

Comment: When started the `One-File Program` creates a temporary folder. Inside this folder there should be your `.xlsx`. **First**, try to find the *temporary folder** and verify your `.xlsx` ist there. [bundling-to-one-file](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#bundling-to-one-file)

Comment: Once the pyinstaller completed, it crated 2 Folders and 1 .spec file. Folder 1: build. Folder 2: dist. and the .SPEC file: gmplotguiwithQT2Radius.spec. When looking inside the folders created I do not see a temp file.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did find the temp folder in my temp directory in my local PC not within the project folder and noticed that the .xlsx file was not in the temp folder.

Comment: @Leo  this temp file and putting the dependency creates lot of issues. Is there a way we can point out the pyinstaller to collate all dependency and keep in same directory where from the exe are generated. I am struck with this issue ,May be you can help with your experience https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807817/python-pyinstaller-created-executable-failed-to-run-the-exe-error-cannot-find-t

Comment: @stovfl i have the above query can you help resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your Command is right. You just need to have both .exe and .xlsx files in one folder. And before that, when commanding `pyinstaller` you should have that .xlsx file in that folder with .py program file. It worked for me!