# python PyInstaller created executable failed to run the exe Error: cannot find Temp\\_MEI175682 (data file)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, executable, pyinstaller

Using PyInstaller created an exe for my script and while running the exe it throws the following error where as if i run the .py file no issues found.

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\my_username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI175682\\resources\\template.json'
[13396] Failed to execute script my_script`

I've supplied all the proper flags for the data to be included by PyInstaller and the creation of the exe passed successfully.

I have used `--add-data` flag and I have used `data` field in the spec file.

[Edit this line and add exact command you have given for creating exe]

Did deepdive in the error given directory path where no such directory or file exist. Could not locate **Temp\_MEI175682**

```
'C:\\Users\\my_username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI175682\\resources\\template.json'
```

The pyinstaller is intalled in .\scripts\ directory ;why pyinstaller is looking the .json file in the above directory where the file does not exist.

Also the file(template.json') is there in the .\scripts\template.json directory.

To solve this issue what is the best way ?
1.Should something be added in the environment variable to resolve this?
2.Should i create single file .exe by running the script from .\scripts\pyinstaller folder only ?
3. Supplying any details to .spec file or adding certain details to .spec file after pyinstaller creating it would help solving this problem?

Any help that would solve the problem with details is much appreciated.Thanks in advance.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get solution for this ,I am facing the similar issue.Let me know if any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the easy and clean solution,Check and like and vote.

When you're encountering following error.

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI502322\\resources\\template.json'
```

This solution tested under Python 2.7.10 and Pyinstaller 3.0.

Put this file to your script folder. 
where your .py script available example **123.py**

Add this hook to your distribution it means add this in below in new file, example xyx.py and keep this file where the 123.py file available

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

#Instruct pyinstaller to collect data files from resources package.
datas = collect_data_files('resources')
```

since this is the error C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI175682\resources\template.json "**resources**" is the package where from you have to take the data file.

Now run the following in command window from your 123.py folder

> pyinstaller --onefile --additional-hooks-dir=. 123.py

exe will be created run the exe and check it is taking the data file.

thanks to [Panda1100](https://community.plot.ly/t/python-exe-cannot-find-default-schema-json/6864/5)